# OS independent keyboard event to character mapping 

Tags: javascript, dojo, keyevent, os-dependent

Obviously, a web application needs to adjust to the user's keyboard settings, right? Is there a way to tell Dojo to make a connection to the actual KeyPress event instead of KeyDown, so we can get the character typed from `event.charCode`?

Since we live in an international world, with multiple operating systems and what not, this information is not sufficient to find out what character the user actually typed, unless I have some function built into the browser to ask the operating system.

As an example, on a German keyboard on Linux, [ is reached via Alt Gr-8, which sends a keydown for Alt and then a keydown with [. Fine, just ignore the first part. On a windows system with a German keyboard, the second event is for an 8 with ctrlKey and altKey set true. Which I don't think JavaScript code should interpret hard-coded, because with other keyboard settings, this key combo will actually mean a different character.

As another example (probably not connected to Dojo, but rather a different programmer's glitch, sorry for the ranting …), with a US keyboard on mac, you can't type the German character ß within the outlook web interface – because outlook bogusly(!) hijacks the alt key (which on the mac is exclusively used to modify the characters typed) to trigger actions and alt-s is thus remapped to mean send. Typically in the middle of a word, of course.

Comment: +1 for bashing Outlook. One of the worst softwares I've ever had to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the 5th `dontFix` argument passed to `dojo.connect()` to true, which tells it to let it pass thru as-is without the special handling. See https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/_base/connect.js#L32

Answer (score 2):

`event.charCode` contains the character that was produced from the keyboard press, not the actual key that was pressed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes

> In a keypress event, the Unicode value of the key pressed is stored in either the keyCode or charCode property, never both. If the key pressed generates a character (e.g. 'a'), charCode is set to the code of that character, respecting the letter case

**edit:** Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Keypress_Event, it contains a more insightful explanation as to how charCode works (specifically in Gecko, but some of it applies to other browsers too). You might find this interesting:

> ... when the **currently selected keyboard layout** produces a Unicode character (according to the current state of CapsLock and NumLock), the charCode property contains that character

Comment: You are, of course, right – the problem here is “just” that `dojo.connect(foo, "onkeypress", this. this.onKeyPress)` connects to the DOM event KeyDown. Which sends the wrong values. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Christopher: Dojo does that?? If so, ditch it.

Comment: @Tim, sadly, it [really does](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/_base/connect.js#L32). I don't use Dojo, but I had to take a look at their source to see if they really do something like that

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keypress` event, whose purpose is to give you information about the character typed by the user. You'll need (bizarrely) the `keyCode` property in IE and the `which` property in other browsers; these give you the character code typed.

The definitive page for JavaScript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    alert(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
};
```